# SSH to cluster under a VPN

Tags: ssh, vpn

My university requires that I connect to VPN, in order to connect to our cluster. I have, after a long struggle, managed to connect to the VPN using the FortiClient VPN command line interface.

My problem is that when I now try to ssh to the particular cluster, the connection times out.

I have successfully connected to the cluster, using Windows with FortiClient and Putty, and was thus wondering how to do this on ubuntu?

I am running Ubuntu 13.04, with `uname -a` giving:

```
uname -a
Linux Nirvana 3.8.0-35-generic #50-Ubuntu SMP Tue Dec 3 01:24:59 UTC 2013 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Comment: Sounds pretty straight forward, are you sure that the vpn is set up correctly? can you telnet to the cluster on the ssh port (22)?